# What is this show about girls that use "spirits" to fight?

Tags: mai-hime

**Genre:** Probably Shoujo/Fantasy or magic

**Type of media:** TV show/OVA?

**Characters:** Mostly girls with one main heroine and a male protagonist living in modern times (school attendance was probably involved)

**Plot:** The story revolves around girls with "spirits" they use to fight. The main heroine was using a "fire spirit" but only after she accepted it in one of the episodes. There also was a smaller girl, which was firstly her rival but they became friends after some time. The little girl was using a huge sword and in one scene in park lot she cut a car in half. Apart from the girls there is also a love story involved with the main heroine and a boy. In the end they have to fight some evil villain.

**Time range:** I watched it around year 2006?

I know this is as vague as it can get, but if someone could recognize it - it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to use past tense in your question on the first line, also could you try to add more information to your question thanks [if possible].

Comment: Edited - added few details. Can't remember much more however.

Comment: Female MC with fire spirits... Does she have two friends with Wind and Water spirits/element?

Comment: Yes, I think the other spirits were related to elements. Also if I recall it correctly the fire spirit had a form of a white serpent? Then when she "absorbed" him, she had two rings around her wrists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the first title that appeared in my mind when reading your description were these three animes called....

**Magic Knight Rayeart** [(MAL Page)](http://myanimelist.net/anime/435/Magic_Knight_Rayearth)
But then it only fits "The main heroine was using a "fire spirit" but only after she accepted it in one of the episodes ...The little girl was using a huge sword... In the end they have to fight some evil villain." and it won't fit "living in modern times"

But then, when I tried googling, I also found....

**Shakugan no Shana** [(MAL Page)](http://myanimelist.net/anime/355/Shakugan_no_Shana)
It fits "The main heroine was using a "fire spirit"..., ...firstly her rival but they became friends after some time. The little girl was using a huge sword too. Apart from the girls there is also a love story involved with the main heroine and a boy. In the end they have to fight some evil villain." and are "living in modern times".

But after searching more thoroughly, I found....

**Mai-HiMe** [(MAL Page)](http://myanimelist.net/anime/98/Mai-HiME) [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My-HiME)
It seems to fit most of your description.

Sorry for this kind of random guess, but well even if none of them is the answer, at least it makes the possibility getting narrower...

Comment: I don't think its Shakugan no Shana. Maybe the other two might be though.

Comment: My guess is `Mai-HiMe` too.  The main character is Mai, and the girl with the sword is Mikoto.

Comment: Mai-HiMe it is my good sir! Wikipages cover image was enough to know it's the right one. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds kind of like [Kaze no Stigma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaze_no_Stigma) (Stigma of the Wind). A 24 episode series that aired back in 2007.

[image]

Here's [ANN's synopsis](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=7473):

> Ayano is the heir to the house of Kannagi, a house with ties to the spirit of fire, whose members are all fire users. All except for her cousin, Kazuma. After he was defeated by Ayano, his father banished him from the house in disgrace. Kazuma ran off and changed his surname to Yagami. He formed a contract with the spirit of wind and becomes a powerful wind user. Four years later, he returned.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the series. The main female protagonist never used a sword. From what i remember...

Answer (score -1):

First thing that popped into my mind was date a live because u said "the story revolves around girls with "spirits" they use to fight." And
 using a "fire spirit" but only after she accepted it in one of the episodes. There also was a smaller girl, which was firstly her rival but they became friends after some time.
The one who was the heroine didn't use a fire spirit but there was a female who did and accepted it in the series and there is also a girl spirit who uses a huge sword and the main heroine is a boy. I hope this helped